# JPA query for selecting entities based on contains clause doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
Country.java 
  String state;
  String city;
```

We would like to query all entries which contains a certain keyword (`select * from countries where state=<state> and city like %Ch%`)

```
Page<List<Country>> findByStateAndCityContainingIgnoreCase(String state, String city, Pageable pageable);
```

The above query is not fetching the results from the database, we expect JPA to construct the proper query, but we always get empty results

Answer (score 0):

`Page` has a list of elements inside. You can access it via `getContent()` method. So return `Page` instead of `Page<List>`.

```
Page<Country> findByStateAndCityContainingIgnoreCase(String state, String city, Pageable pageable);
```